# Why is main's return not an exit code?

Tags: haskell, exit-code

C and C++ allow us to return an exit code from `main`. Why does Haskell not do the same? Seems to me that it would be simple enough; just require `main :: IO Int` rather than `IO t`.

I realize that the following will not behave as a C programmer might expect:

```
main :: IO Int
main = do
    return 1                   -- Execution continues, thanks to (>>)
    putStrLn "Unreachable?"
    return 2                   -- Exit code 2?
```

This sort of exit code might be tricky to do right, but how tricky really? Seems nicer to me than having to import `System.Exit`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not worth it. 99% of Haskell programs would just do `return 0`, that's pure boilerplate. It adds an extra very specific channel for errors, when exceptions (which `System.Exit` leverages) already do just as fine a job. How often do you actually need to import `System.Exit` for fine-grained return codes?

Comment: To support the "boilerplate" claim: Java has `void main(String[] args)` so that programmers do not have to add `return 0;` at the end most of the time. If you want some other return code, you call a library routine. C++ is even more peculiar since `int main()` has an implicit `return 0;` at the end, and this implicit return is added only to `main`.

Comment: As a bizarre aside... `main` is already not required to have the type `IO () `. It can be any type at all with `IO` as the top level constructor. Using the return value instead of throwing it away would only be a little awful. I think the bigger issue is that exit codes change meaning across operating systems, and one could imagine an OS that uses a totally different type for exit statuses. It's not a fundamentally portable part of a program.